# nginx + regex, remove all parts of URI except the last one

Tags: nginx, rewrite, regex, remove, uri

With an URI like

```
/a-part/some-part/another-part/last-part/?some_param=some_value
```

how do I go about removing everything up to the last part with params and ultimately rewrite it to look like

```
/index.php?id=last-part&some_param=some_value
```

?. I tried all kinds of magic but the closest I got was removing everything up to question mark.

Comment: You don't even need a rewrite for that. Just put it in `try_files`.

Comment: I was wanting to ask what you have in mind with try_files until I noticed that my question wasn't exactly correct. I'm sorry about that overlook. The problem is that I need to trow out the last part as an 'id' argument and glue remaining arguments to it. I don't think try_files is that powerfull.

Comment: is nginx regex like apache's mod_rewrite?
`RewriteRule ^.*/(.*)/?\?(.*)$ /index.php?id=$1&$2` ... We need a regex exchange...

Comment: Pretty much yes, except nginx doesn't need a "RewriteCond" and "RewriteRule" is just "rewrite".

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it. This is what seems to be working:

```
rewrite /?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1&$2 last;
```